# Pass parameters from dynamically added input fields to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I have a form which has multiple input fields that will be added dynamically when user click the Add button.

I already managed to achieve this, but the problem I am facing now is I cannot pass the parameters that has been added dynamically using JavaScript function, to a servlet.

This is the code of dynamically adding multiple input fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;

$("#addDynamicDivs").click(function () {
    var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv1');
     newTextBoxDiv1.attr("style",'float: left;');

     var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2');
     newTextBoxDiv2.attr("style",'float: left;');

     var newTextBoxDiv3 = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv3');
     newTextBoxDiv3.attr("style",'float: left;');

     var newTextBoxDiv4 = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv4');
     newTextBoxDiv4.attr("style",'float: left;');

     newTextBoxDiv1.after().html('<label  class="inputlabel2">Speaker Name : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="speakername" id="speakername" value="" >');
      newTextBoxDiv2.after().html('<label  class="inputlabel2">Speaker Country : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="speakercountry" id="speakercountry" value="" >');
      newTextBoxDiv3.after().html('<label  class="inputlabel2">Speaker Company : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="speakercompany" id="textbox" value="" >');
      newTextBoxDiv4.after().html('<label  class="inputlabel2">Speaker Desc : </label>' +
      '<textarea name="speakerdesc" id="speakerdesc" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>');

      newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      newTextBoxDiv3.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      newTextBoxDiv4.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    });
});
</script>
```

It appears that the only parameters passed to the servlet are from the form, not including the parameters from the dynamically added input fields.

How can I pass all the parameters from the function to the servlet?

Thanks,

raz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the dynamic params inside the form. You should put inside the form the div elemt where you are including the dynamic params.

```
<form>
    <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
    </div>
</form>
```